# can not send email to own domain, but can for other domain like as gmail

Tags: email, php

I want to send a new password by email when a user forgets their password to login to my site. The email fails to send unless it's a Gmail address. Can anyone explain what the problem is?

```
<?php
$email_address=$_POST['email_to'];
$tbl_name=user;

$query="SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$email_address'";
$st=mysql_query($query);
$recs=mysql_num_rows($st);

if ($recs == 0)
{
    echo "<center><font face='Verdana' size='2' color=red><b>No Password</b><br> Sorry Your address is not there in our database . You can signup and login to use our site. <BR><BR>       </center>";
    exit;
}


if ($recs == 1){
function makeRandomPassword() 
{
$salt = "abchefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
$i = 0;
while ($i <= 7) 
{
$num = rand() % 33;
$tmp = substr($salt, $num, 1);
$pass = $pass . $tmp;
   $i++;
}
   return $pass;
}

$random_password = makeRandomPassword();
$db_password = md5($random_password);

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET   password='$db_password',display_pass='$random_password'  WHERE email='$email_address'");

echo "New Password has been send to your email.";
echo "<a href='index.php'>Back</a>";

//------- SEND MAIL FORM --------

$to=$email_address;
$subject="Your password here";

$header="from: Admin Ayam Kampung Lingnan <your email>";

// Your message
$messages= "Password Anda untuk login ke website Lingnan \r\n";
$messages.="Password Anda Adalah: $random_password \r\n";
$messages.="Mohon untuk tidak di balas, karena ini adalah email otomatis \r\n";

// send email
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$messages,$header);

}
}
?>
```

Comment: Alternative method: PHPMailer using SMTP: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsmtp

Comment: You should also find out about SQL injection. Your example script is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

Your header line is invalid.

If a From header contains a name and that name contains spaces, the name should be quoted.

Try:

```
$header="From: \"Admin Ayam Kampung Lingnan\" <emailaddress@example.com>";
```

Although, you should consider that sending from any email address that isn't your mail server's local domain, has a strong chance of being blocked at some point, or is at least more likely to be marked as spam.